# Replace mutliple occurances in delimited columns

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace multiple occurrences of a pattern in a delimited split with the information in another delimited split.

My delimiter is pipe and in this example I want to replace every occurrence in column three with my label in column two.

so if I have a file with the contents:

```
33|29|aa aa aa aa aa
28|12|aa aa aa aa aa
11|12|aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
9|9|aa aa aa aa
```

I want the output to be:

```
33|29|29 29 29 29 29
28|12|12 12 12 12 12
11|12|12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
9|9|9 9 9 9
```

What I have thought of is using sed with back references like this:

```
sed 's/|\([0-9][0-9]*\)|\(aa *\)/|\1|\1 /g'
```

but I don't know how to repeat this automatically and it will only substitute the first occurrence.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. What you're trying to do is not that so it's not a job for sed. Also, sed doesn't know anything about columns/fields so from that standpoint alone you shouldn't be considering sed for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`, assumes second column is always made up of `[0-9]` characters and third column doesn't have digits

```
$ sed -E ':a s/^([^|]+\|)([^|]+)(\|[0-9 ]*)[^0-9 ]+/\1\2\3\2/; ta' ip.txt 
33|29|29 29 29 29 29
28|12|12 12 12 12 12
11|12|12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
9|9|9 9 9 9
```

- `:a` label `a`
- `^([^|]+\|)` first column and `|`
- `([^|]+)` second column value
- `(\|[0-9 ]*)` saves `|` and any sequence of digits and space

  - will match only `|` in first iteration
  - `|` and first replaced value and spaces in second iteration and so on
- `[^0-9 ]+` the characters to be replaced
- `ta` branch to label `a` as long as there is a match

Realized later that number of back references can be reduced:

```
sed -E ':a s/^([^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[0-9 ]*)[^0-9 ]+/\1\2/; ta' ip.txt
```

With `awk`. Thanks @EdMorton for suggestions

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub(/[^ ]+/, $2, $3)} 1' ip.txt 
33|29|29 29 29 29 29
28|12|12 12 12 12 12
11|12|12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
9|9|9 9 9 9
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` Set input/output field separator as `|`
- `gsub("[^ ]+", $2, $3)` replace all sequences of non-space characters with value of `$2`. Do this only on third column
- `1` idiomatic way to print each line
- Assumes second column doesn't contain `&` as it is special character in replacement section. See [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-sub_0028_0029-function-1)

Comment: I want to upvote the awk solution but don't want my upvote taken as approval of the sed solution since this is clearly NOT a job for sed so I'm not sure what to do. Btw, the first arg for `gsub()` is a regexp, not a string, so use regexp delimiters or you're forcing awk to convert your string to a regexp before using it and so impacting performance and introducing caveats. It's also worth giving the OP a heads up that the script will produce unexpected results if `$2` contains an `&` but it's probably OK for this usage.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks as usual :) especially the catch on `gsub`... and yeah, `sed` is clearly not suited here.. just time pass on lazy Sunday evening..

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -F'\|' -lanE 'print join("|",@F[0,1],$F[2]=~s/\b(\S+)\b/$F[1]/gr)' file
```

output

```
33|29|29 29 29 29 29
28|12|12 12 12 12 12
11|12|12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
9|9|9 9 9 9
```

Needs `perl -v` v5.14 or higher. Or

```
perl -F'\|' -lanE 'print join("|",@F[0,1],map{s/\b(\S+)\b/$F[1]/g;$_}$F[2])'
```

for any perl version.

EDIT:
**very nice** @Sundeep's solution

```
perl -F'\|' -ape 's/.*\|\K.*/$&=~s|[^ ]+|$F[1]|gr/e'
```

Comment: another alternative: `perl -F'\|' -ape 's/.*\|\K.*/$&=~s|[^ ]+|$F[1]|gr/e'`

Comment: @Sundeep **higher order regexes!** :) Nice trick doing substituions in nested evaluation...

Comment: ability to use Perl code in replacement section is very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You want commands like

```
sed 's/.*|\([0-9][0-9]*\)|.*/\/\1\/s#aa#\1#g/' inputfile
```

Use `sed` twice:

```
sed -f <(sed 's/.*|\([0-9][0-9]*\)|.*/\/\1\/s#aa#\1#g/' inputfile) inputfile
```

EDIT:
And how about overlapping keys like `..|1234|..` and `..|123|..` ?
Use the improvement that @potong suggested in his/her comment.

Comment: I think you may need to be line specific otherwise you may hit false positives i.e. `sed -f <(sed -r 's/.*\|(.*)\|.*/s#aa#\1#g/' file | cat -n -) file`

Answer (score 0):

awk would be my choice as it involves columns:

```
awk -F'|' 'gsub(/aa/,$2)' file
```

IF there is a possibility of data in other columns (separated by pipes) to not be changed, then simply include $3 in the gsub call.

And as I learned just recently, if you want the filed edited as it stands and are using gawk, you can also include '-i inplace' and the data will be changed for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{split($1,a,"|");gsub(a[3],a[2])}1' fil
33|29|29 29 29 29 29
28|12|12 12 12 12 12
11|12|12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
9|9|9 9 9 9
```

Here, First column is divided into chunks using `split` function and then `gsub` took care or replacement.

Comment: Have some courtesy to explain why the downvote ? Is there something wrong which can be avoided in future ?